# confusion about chaining $q promises with angular and typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, promise, q

I'm pretty inexperienced with `Q`, `promises`, `angular`, and `typescript` - so it seemed the obviously intelligent choice was to try using them all together!

Basically I have some methods setup to return `Q.IPromise<T>` so that I can chain a `then(f)` statement onto them. Both of them work fine;

```
public Clear = (): Q.IPromise<IArticle> => {
        var deferred = this.$q.defer();
        this.$http({
            url: String.format('{0}{1}', this.$settings.uri(), '/api/cancel/article'),
            responseType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true
        }).then((response: IArticleRequest) => {
            deferred.resolve(response.data.article);
        }, (response) => {
            deferred.reject(null);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

public Fetch = (id: string):Q.IPromise<IArticleRequestData> => {
        var deferred = this.$q.defer();
        this.$http({
            url: String.format('{0}{1}{2}', this.$settings.uri(), '/api/articles/fetch/', id),
            responseType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true
        }).then((response: IArticleRequest) => {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, (response) => {
            deferred.reject(null);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

So I can use them like this;

```
$articles.Fetch(1).then((r: IArticleRequestData) => {
    $articles.Clear().then((n:IArticle) => {
        console.log('completed!');
    })
});
```

That works fine - and as I expect it to.

But now, I need **another** step - a *last* call sort of. Another `then(f)` function that goes on the outermost function but doesn't occur until the innermost one completes.

So in short, I need this;

```
$articles.Fetch(1).then((r: IArticleRequestData) => {
    $articles.Clear().then((n:IArticle) => {
        // inner function completed
    })
}).then((l:any)=> {
    // occurs after everything else is done and inner
    // functions are finished
});
```

and I'm having a very difficult time figuring out how to make this happen. Is this even possible with the way promises work?

### extra notes

adding another function to the inner section is allowable but it feels like the wrong approach. this is my go to "fix" if I absolutely cannot figure out the way I'm asking about, or if the way I'm trying to do it is just wrong.

I want the extra `then` on the outside because the inner methods are actually responsible for resolving certain things, and as such they may split off into other tangents or `deferred` methods as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the promise from the inner function like this:

```
$articles.Fetch(1).then((r: IArticleRequestData) => {
    return $articles.Clear()
}).then((l:any)=> {
    // occurs after everything else is done and inner
    // functions are finished
});
```

Comment: Hrnm. That only works if the `Clear` function gets called. Is there anything else I can do to get to that step in case something different happens inside the first `then()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can return any promise inside of the `then` method and chain onto that. Since you can make your own promises, you can make them do whatever you want.

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you very much!